# JSON.NET WriteRaw putting extra data and closing bracket on output

Tags: c#, json.net, nreco

So I've made a custom JsonConverter that seems to do just perfectly serializing an object and deserializing it.

Specifically, I'm serializing an FFProbe output via NReco.VideoInfo:

```
public class NMediaInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{  
     public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        var n = ((MediaInfo) value).Result.CreateNavigator();
        n.MoveToRoot();
        var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(n.ReadSubtree());

        writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xDoc, serializer.Formatting)); 
    }
```

And if I serialize it thusly:

```
File.WriteAllText("myfile.json"), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(videoInfo, Formatting.Indented, new NMediaInfoConverter()));
```

Life is good.  The files are perfect, and they deserialize without a problem.

Now if I make an encapsulating class, and decorate the property with the NMediaInfoConverter:

```
class MyMediaInfo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NMediaInfoConverter))]
    public NReco.VideoInfo.MediaInfo NMediaInfo { get; set; }
}
```

At the very end of my JSON, I get an extra space, "null", a linefeed, and an extra closing bracket:

```
 null
```

}

Am I missing the point, somewhere?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object. when using custom `JsonConverter<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54441810/3744182) in that you need to call `WriteRawValue()` instead of `WriteRaw()`.  Can't say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: OK, from your answer it looks like `WriteRawValue()` was the answer.  Shall I make this a duplicate then?

Comment: @dbc - You're absolutely correct.  I found a blog post on the existence of this issue / bug / whatever in my answer below.

Seeing this answer, though, makes it make more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate.  Not sure why I didn't find that answer in the searches I made.

Comment: Probably because your code doesn't throw an exception, which was the symptom in the other question.

Comment: @dbc, oddly enough:  After I made this post, I added another property "below" the one in my post, and it started throwing an exception, then.  Prior to that, it had no problem writing invalid JSON to its output.

Comment: Sometimes [`JsonWriter.AutoCompleteOnClose = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_AutoCompleteOnClose.htm) (which is [the default](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs#L353)) can obscure bugs in JSON converters when the bug occurs writing the very last item in the file.

Comment: @dbc - Thanks!  I'm going to remember that one!